# HTML/CSS : Vertical border overlapping horizontal border

Tags: html, css, border, html-table

Here is the fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/AV38G/

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr class="first-line">
        <td class="first-column">Some</td>
        <td>Foobar</td>
        <td>Stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="first-column">foobar</td>
        <td>raboof</td>
        <td>184</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="first-column">bar</td>
        <td>87458</td>
        <td>184</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="first-column">874</td>
        <td>raboof</td>
        <td>foobar</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

CSS:

```
/* ACTUAL CSS */
table {
    width: 300px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr td.first-column{
    border-left: none;
}
tr.first-line {
    border-bottom: 3px solid green;
    border-top: none;
}
tr.first-line td {
    border-left: none;
}
td {
    border-left: 3px solid red;
}
tr {
    border-top: 3px solid red;
}
```

Ugly, right. So why the red border overwrite/override the green border ?

How can I get the "untouched" horizontal green bordel ? (no HTML5/CSS3 please, accessibility purposes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That behavior is caused because you are collapsing the border of the table, use `border-spacing: 0;` instead, call a class on the first data row and than I've used the selector below to turn off the `border-top`

```
.second-row td {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AV38G/5/) (Tested on chrome and firefox)

```
/* ACTUAL CSS */
table {
    width: 300px;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

tr td.first-column{
    border-left: none;
}

td {
    border-left: 3px solid red;
    border-top: 3px solid red;
}

tr.first-line td {
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid green;
    border-top: none;
}

.second-row td {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Thank you :) and that was a real sportsmanship as you got some good votes on your answer, but unfortunately it was not cross browser...